# How do Media queries differentiate big smatphone resolution and low tablet resolution displays

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Example:

Samsung galaxy S7    - 5.1 inch,    1440 x 2560 px  - smartphone

Acer Iconia Tab A500 - 10.1 inch,    800 x 1280 px  - tablet

If I set @media screen and (max-width: 480px), this should recognize a smartphone.
How can that be possible if a the tablet has a lower resolution.

Do media queries measure something else and not the real resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit `px` in CSS is a *reference pixel*, not a physical pixel:

> The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm's length, 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).
>
> (Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 2 (CSS 2.2) Specification, [section 4.3.3. Lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#length-units))

Commonly, `1px` is one physical pixel on devices which have a "standard definition" pixel density of around 90-120 pixels/inch. Desktop browsers tend to keep `1px` equal to what they believe to be one device pixel.

How many device pixels correspond to `1px` depends on the pixel density of the device and the magnification level. At the default magnification level

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

the S7 uses about 3.5 device pixels for `1px`.

To distinguish devices with high pixel density you can use

```
@media screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
  /* This is a high-dpi device */
}
```

Comment: Thank yout very much!
That was the answer I was looking for the whole week! :) 
People just explain which query to use for which devices but nobody tended to explain how to clearly imagine and undestand all that variations.
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Elano7: If the answer solved the your problem, you may consider accepting it, so that future readers will know they can use it.

Comment: I klicked on the tick to make it green. I hope that was the acception process.